# PHP switch in email contact form is not sending to the correct address

Tags: php, html

I'm creating an HTML contact form that uses php to send emails to 6 different people depending on the selection the user makes. The code I have sends the email but it's only sending to the default. I'm not sure what needs to change to make the switch work. sendTo is pulling from the HTML page. I've put the code below.

```
// Check if the form has been posted

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // The email address the email will be sent to
    switch ($_POST['$sendTo'])
    {
    case "membership":
      $sendTo = "email1";
      break;
    case "performance":
      $sendTo = "email2";
      break;
    case "quartets":
      $sendTo = "email3";
      break;
    case "president":
      $sendTo = "email4";
      break;
    case "regional":
      $sendTo = "email5";
      break;
    case "website":
      $sendTo = "email6";
      break;
    default:
      $sendTo = "email6";
    }


    // The email subject
    $subject = "Contact Form Submission";
    // Set the from and reply-to address for the email
    $headers =  'From: Organization <webmaster@organization.com>' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    // Build the body of the email
    $mailbody = "You have received an email from the POB website contact form.\n\n"
              . "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n"
              . "Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n"
              . "Heard From: " . $_POST['howhear'] . "\n"
              . "Message:\n" . $_POST['message'];
    // Send the email
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $mailbody, $headers);
    // Go to the thank you page
    header("location: thankyou.shtml");
    exit;

}


<p><strong>Who do you want to contact?</strong><br/> 
    <select name="sendTo">  
        <option value="none">Select a Contact</option>
        <option value="performance">Performance Manager</option>
        <option value="membership">Membership Chair</option>
        <option value="president">President</option>
        <option value="quartets">Quartet Promotion Chair</option>
        <option value="regional">Regional Events Coordinator</option>
        <option value="website">Website</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

If the user selects Membership Chair on the HTML page, it should send to the membership email. Same for the other cases.

Comment: I don't see where you set `$sendTo` anywhere before your switch statement. I then don't see where you assemble `$email`

Comment: yeah than sendTo is not a PHP variable $sendTo. It can accessed with $_POST['sendTo']

Comment: Without the $ inside the $_POST['...'] just `$_POST['sendTo']` not `$_POST['$sendTo']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your Code. You try to get the POST Information '$sendTo' but your actual Information is `$_POST['sendTo']`

```
switch($_POST['sendTo']){
  case "membership":
    $sendTo = "email1..";
    break;
  ...
}
```

In PHP $ is used to indicate that the following is a variable, but in your case you already use the variable $_POST which contains information about the active POST Request. Inside of $_POST is a Infomation accessed with `$_POST['sendTo']` which contains the value selected in the HTML Form.

Comment: Right now sendTo is coming from the HTML page. I'll add the code for the drop list it is pulling from in the original question.

Comment: ahh sendTo is the name of your form field, right? than the switch is `switch($_POST['sendTo']){...}`

Comment: Oh. So I need to add the $_POST. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work. Still sent to what I have set as "email6" in the example. I tried with single quotes and double quotes as Aaron commented above.

Comment: string(22) "_email address_" 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/pobc1993/public_html/contact_us1.php:30) in /home1/pobc1993/public_html/contact_us1.php on line 48

Comment: I left out the actual email address it spit back out. It was "email6" in the example.

Comment: Please read my edited Question and try to remove the $ in ['$sendTo'].

Comment: I didn't get an email that time. I'm guessing it worked!! I need to contact the person to whom it sent to see if they actually got it. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to submit the information about the type (membership, performance etc) with the form and use this value in a switch case.
Lets say the variable is simply called "sendTo". (edited the variable name)

```
switch ($_POST["sendTo"])
    {
    case "membership":
      $sendTo = "email1";
      break;
    case "performance":
      $sendTo = "email2";
      break;
    case "quartets":
      $sendTo = "email3";
      break;
    case "president":
      $sendTo = "email4";
      break;
    case "regional":
      $sendTo = "email5";
      break;
    case "website":
      $sendTo = "email6";
      break;
    default:
      $sendTo = "email6";
    }
```

Comment: I tried using switch ($_POST['$sendTo']) and it did the same thing. It's sending an email to what I have set as "email6" in my example. I updated my code above to show what I have now.

Comment: @amlynn18 I updated my code, should be working now. Best regards